# How to transfer data between several activities

Tags: android

I am making a game and this game has several levels,but I have to make an activity for each level,In this game ,the user takes 5 scores after the end of each level and enters the next level with an intent button,And I got into the problem of transferring scores between activities and collecting scores/Thank you very much...

score1+score2+score3+....

---

one activity

```
     button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(L1.this,L2.class);

            intent.putExtra("key",score);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });   score += 5;
    ((TextView) findViewById(txt_score)).setText(getString(R.string.score) + " " + score);
}}
```

Please necessary codes for next activities

---

two activity

```
   ???????
```

three activity

```
  ??????
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are putting the score in the intent, in the onCreate() of your second and third activities you can access the intent through getIntent(). With this, you can do something like:

```
int previousScore = getIntent().getIntExtra("key", -1);
```

to retrieve the score from the previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist data across several Activities there are multiple choices e.g. Bundles, shared preferences, SQLite db, ect but I would suggest using a POJO. Otherwise you will have to continue passing your score from Activity A, to Activity B, to Activity C and so forth in the case of a Bundle. And shared preferences and SQLite may not be worth the effort if the data is throw away. To begin, create a simple model class

```
public class ScoreModel {
    private static int mScore; // note the static modifier

    // create setters/getters
    public static void setScore(int score) {
       mScore = score;
    }

    public static int getScore() {
       return mScore;
    }
}
```

Now from any of your Activities you can retrieve your score and even update it.

From your Activity to set score: `ScoreModel.setScore(<your value>);`

From your Activity to retrieve score: `int score = ScoreModel.getScore();`